# Maximum Recursion Occurs, what went wrong in Keller Box?

Tags: python, numpy

This is the non syntax error code, but i cant seem to fix the recursion error. need some help here. the algorithm based on matlab, i've read the tutorial on matlab but i can seem to figure out which part did i miss.

```
import numpy as npy


blt = int(raw_input("Input the boundary layer thickness = "))
deleta = float(raw_input("Input the step size of boundary layer thickness = "))
np = int((blt/deleta) + 1)
stop = 1
k=1
l=2
g=2
eselon = 0.00001

def eta(j,k):
    if j == 1 and k == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return eta(j-1,k) + deleta;
deta = deleta
def etanp():
    return eta(np,k)       
def f(j,k):
    return -eta(np,1)*etab2 + etanp()*etab1 + eta(j,1)
def u(j,k):
    return  -3*etab1 + 2*etab +1
def v(j,k):
    return (-6/etanp()*etab + (2/etanp()))
def fb(j,k):
    return 0.5 * (f(j,k) + f(j-1,k))
def ub(j,k):
    return 0.5 * (u(j,k) + u(j-1,k))
def vb(j,k):
    return 0.5*(v(j,k) + v(j-1,k))
def fvb(j,k):
    return fb(j,k)*vb(j,k)
def uub(j,k):
    return ub(j,k) * ub(j,k)

def a1(j,k):
    return 1 + 0.5*deta *fb(j,k)
def a2(j,k):
    return -1 + 0.5*deta *fb(j,k)
def a3(j,k):
    return 0.5 * deta * vb(j,k)
def a4(j,k):
    return a3(j,k)
def a5(j,k):
    return -1 * deta * ub(j,k)
def a6(j,k):
    return a5(j,k)

def r1(j,k):
    return f(j-1,k) - f(j,k) + deta * ub(j,k)
def r2(j,k):
    return u(j-1,k) - u(j,k) + deta * vb(j,k)
def r3(j,k):
    return v(j-1,k)-v(j,k) - deta *((fvb(j,k)*uub(j,k)))-deta

def AJ(j,k):
    if j == 2:
        return npy.matrix([[0,1,0],[-0.5*deta,0,-0.5*deta],[a2(2,k), a3(2,k), a1(2,k)]])
    else:
        return npy.matrix([[-0.5*deta,0,0],[-1,0,-0.5*deta],[a6(j,k),a3(j,k),a1(j,k)]])
def BJ(j,k):
    return npy.matrix([[0,-1,0],[0,0,-0.5*deta],[0,a4(j,k),a2(j,k)]])
def CJ(j,k):
    return npy.matrix([[-0.5*deta,0,0],[1,0,0],[a5(j,k),0,0]])

def alfa(j,k):
    if j == 2:
        return AJ(2,k)

    else:   
        return AJ(j,k) - (BJ(j,k)*gamma(j-1,k))
def gamma(j,k):
    if j == 2:
        return npy.matrix.I((alfa(2,k))*CJ(2,k))
    else:
        return npy.matrix.I((alfa(j,k))*CJ(j,k))
def rr(j,k):
    return npy.matrix([[r1(j,k)],[r2(j,k)],[r3(j,k)]])   
def ww(j,k):
    if j == 2:
        return npy.matrix.I(AJ(2,k)*rr(2,k))
    else:
        return npy.matrix.I((alfa(j,k))*(rr(j,k)-(BJ(j,k)*ww(j-1,k))))

def dell(j,k):
     if j == np:
        return ww(np,k)
     else:   
        return ww(j,k) - (gamma(j,k)*dell(j+1,k))
def delf(j,k):
    if j == 1:
        return 0
    elif j == 2:
        return dell(2,k)[1,0]
    else:
        return dell(j,k)
def delu(j,k):
    if j == 1 or j == np:
        return 0
    elif j == np-1:
        return dell(j,k)[0,0]
def delv(j,k):
    if j == 1:
        return dell(2,k)[0,0]
    elif j == 2:
        return dell(2,k)[2,0]
    else:
        return dell(j,k)[2,0]

def ffinal(j,l):
    return f(j,k) + delf(j,k)
def ufinal(j,l):
    return u(j,k) + delu(j,k)
def vfinal(j,l):
    return v(j,k) + delv(j,k)

# Beginning of calculation for Keller-Box

while stop > eselon:
    eta(1,1)
    for j in range (2,np):
        eta(j,k)  

# Initial condition
    etab = eta(j,k) / eta(np,k)
    etab1 = etab**2
    etab2 = etab**3 
    for j in range (1,np):
        deta
        f(j,1)
        u(j,1)
        v(j,1)

# Current value of Central Differentiation
    for j in range (2,np):
        fb(j,k)
        ub(j,k)
        vb(j,k)
        fvb(j,k)
        uub(j,k)
        a1(j,k)
        a2(j,k)
        a3(j,k)
        r1(j,k)
        r2(j,k)
        r3(j,k)
# Matrices Value for A1, Aj, Bj, and CJ
        CJ(j,k)
        AJ(j,k)
        BJ(j,k)
# Recursion: Forward Sweeping
    for j in range (3,np):
        alfa(j,k)
        gamma(j,k)
    for j in range(2,np):
        rr(j,k)
    for j in range(3,np):
        ww(j,k)

# Recursion: Backward Sweeping
    for j in range (np-1,2,-1):
        dell(j,k)

    for j in range (np,3,-1):
        delu(j-1,k)
        delf(j,k)
        delv(j,k)

# Newton's Method
    for j in range (1,np):
        ffinal(j,l)
        ufinal(j,l)
        vfinal(j,l)

# Check the convergence of iteration
    stop = npy.abs(delv(1,k))
    kmax = k
    k =+ 1

cfrex = vfinal(1,kmax)
print cfrex
```

Here's the referential that i used from mathlab

```
*******************************************************************
Input
*******************************************************************
blt = input ('Input the boundary layer thickness = ');
deleta=0.1; %input('Input the step size of boundary layer thickness=');
np = (blt / deleta)+ 1;
pr = 7; %input ('Input the prandtl number = ');
K = 0; %input ('Input the material parameter K = ');
lambda = 1; %input ('Input the mixed convection parameter = ');
stop = 1.0; k = 1; eselon = 0.00001;
while stop > eselon
eta(1,1) = 0.0;
for j = 2:np
eta(j,1) = eta(j-1,1) + deleta;
end
*******************************************************************
Initial Condition for f, u, v, h, p, s, t
*******************************************************************
etanpq = eta(np,1)/3;
etau15 = 1/eta(np,1);
etau16 = 2/eta(np,1);
etanp = eta(np,1);
for j =1:np
deta(j,k)= deleta;
etab = eta(j,1)/eta(np,1);
etab1 = etab^2;
etab2 = etab^3;
etau152 = etau15^2;
etau162 = etau16^2;
f(j,1) = -etanpq * etab2 + etanp * etab1;
u(j,1) = -etab1 + 2 * etab;
v(j,1) = -etau16 * etab + etau16;
h(j,1) = etau15 * etab - etau15;
p(j,1) = etau152;
s(j,1) = -eta(j,1) + eta(j,1) * etab;
t(j,1) = -1 + 2 * etab;
end
 

*******************************************************************
Current Central Differention Value
*******************************************************************
for j = 2:np
fb(j,k) = 0.5*(f(j,k) + f(j-1,k));
ub(j,k) = 0.5*(u(j,k) + u(j-1,k));
vb(j,k) = 0.5*(v(j,k) + v(j-1,k));
hb(j,k) = 0.5*(h(j,k) + h(j-1,k));
pb(j,k) = 0.5*(p(j,k) + p(j-1,k));
sb(j,k) = 0.5*(s(j,k) + s(j-1,k));
tb(j,k) = 0.5*(t(j,k) + t(j-1,k));
fvb(j,k) = fb(j,k) * vb(j,k);
uub(j,k) = ub(j,k) ^ 2;
pfb(j,k) = pb(j,k) * fb(j,k);
hub(j,k) = hb(j,k) * ub(j,k);
tfb(j,k) = tb(j,k) * fb(j,k);
sub(j,k) = sb(j,k) * ub(j,k);
*******************************************************************
Momentum Differential Equation
*******************************************************************
a1(j,k) = (1.0 + K) + 0.5 * deta(j,k) * fb(j,k);
a2(j,k) = -(1.0 + K) + 0.5 * deta(j,k) * fb(j,k);
a3(j,k) = 0.5 * deta(j,k) * vb(j,k);
a4(j,k) = a3(j,k);
a5(j,k) = -1 * deta(j,k) * ub(j,k);
a6(j,k) = a5(j,k);
a7(j,k) = 0.5 * K * deta(j,k);
a8(j,k) = a7(j,k);
a9(j,k) = 0.5 * lambda * deta(j,k);
a10(j,k) = a9(j,k);
*******************************************************************
Angel Differential
*******************************************************************
b1(j,k) = (1 + K/2) + 0.5 * deta(j,k) * fb(j,k);
b2(j,k) = -(1 + K/2) + 0.5 * deta(j,k) * fb(j,k);
b3(j,k) = 0.5 * deta(j,k) * pb(j,k);
b4(j,k) = b3(j,k);
b5(j,k) = -0.5 * deta(j,k) * hb(j,k);
b6(j,k) = b5(j,k);
b7(j,k) = -0.5 * deta(j,k) * ub(j,k) - K * deta(j,k);
b8(j,k) = b7(j,k);
b9(j,k) = -0.5 * K * deta(j,k);
b10(j,k) = b9(j,k);
 

*******************************************************************
Energy Differential
*******************************************************************
c1(j,k) = 1/pr + 0.5 * deta(j,k) * fb(j,k);
c2(j,k) = -1/pr + 0.5 * deta(j,k) * fb(j,k);
c3(j,k) = 0.5 * deta(j,k) * tb(j,k);
c4(j,k) = c3(j,k);
c5(j,k) = -0.5 * deta(j,k) * sb(j,k);
c6(j,k) = c5(j,k);
c7(j,k) = -0.5 * deta(j,k) * ub(j,k);
c8(j,k) = c7(j,k);
*******************************************************************
Definition value of  rj-1/2
*******************************************************************
r1(j,k) = f(j-1,k) - f(j,k) + deta(j,k) * ub(j,k);
r2(j,k) = u(j-1,k) - u(j,k) + deta(j,k) * vb(j,k);
r3(j,k) = h(j-1,k) - h(j,k) + deta(j,k) * pb(j,k);
r4(j,k) = s(j-1,k) - s(j,k) + deta(j,k) * tb(j,k);
r5(j,k) = (1.0 + K) * (v(j-1,k) - v(j,k)) - deta(j,k) * fvb(j,k) -...
deta(j,k)+ deta(j,k) * uub(j,k) - K * deta(j,k)...
* pb(j,k) - lambda * deta(j,k) * sb(j,k);
r6(j,k) = (1 + K/2) * (p(j-1,k) - p(j,k)) - deta(j,k) * pfb(j,k) + ...
deta(j,k) * hub(j,k) + 2 * K * deta(j,k) * hb(j,k) + ...
K * deta(j,k) * vb(j,k);
r7(j,k) = 1/pr * (t(j-1,k) - t(j,k)) - deta(j,k) * tfb(j,k) +...
deta(j,k) * sub(j,k);
end
*******************************************************************
Matrices Value A1, Aj, Bj, Cj
*******************************************************************
a{2,k} = [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ;...
-0.5 * deta(2,k) 0 0 0 -0.5 * deta(2,k) 0 0;...
0 -0.5 * deta(2,k) 0 0 0 -0.5 * deta(2,k) 0;...
0 0 -1 0 0 0 -0.5 * deta(2,k);...
a2(2,k) a8(2,k) a10(2,k) a3(2,k) a1(2,k) a7(2,k) 0;...
b10(2,k) b2(2,k) 0 b3(2,k) b9(2,k) b1(2,k) 0;...
0 0 c8(2,k) c3(2,k) 0 0 c1(2,k)];

 
for j = 3:np
a{j,k} = [-0.5 * deta(j,k) 0 0 1 0 0 0 ;...
-1 0 0 0 -0.5 * deta(j,k) 0 0 ;...
0 -1 0 0 0 -0.5 * deta(j,k) 0 ;...
0 0 -1 0 0 0 -0.5 * deta(j,k);...
a6(j,k) 0 a10(j,k) a3(j,k) a1(j,k) a7(j,k) 0;...
b6(j,k) b8(j,k) 0 b3(j,k) b9(j,k) b1(j,k) 0;...
c6(j,k) 0 c8(j,k) c3(j,k) 0 0 c1(j,k)];

b{j,k} = [0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 ;...
0 0 0 0 -0.5 * deta(j,k) 0 0;...
0 0 0 0 0 -0.5 * deta(j,k) 0;...
0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5 * deta(j,k);...
0 0 0 a4(j,k) a2(j,k) a8(j,k) 0;...
0 0 0 b4(j,k) b10(j,k) b2(j,k) 0;...
0 0 0 c4(j,k) 0 0 c2(j,k)];
end

for j = 2:np
c{j,k} = [-0.5 * deta(j,k) 0 0 0 0 0 0 ;...
1 0 0 0 0 0 0;...
0 1 0 0 0 0 0;...
0 0 1 0 0 0 0;...
a5(j,k) 0 a9(j,k) 0 0 0 0;...
b5(j,k) b7(j,k) 0 0 0 0 0;...
c5(j,k) 0 c7(j,k) 0 0 0 0];
end

*******************************************************************
Recursion of block Elimination
*******************************************************************
Forward Sweeping
*******************************************************************
alfa{2,k} = a{2,k};
gamma{2,k} = inv(alfa{2,k}) * c{2,k};
for j = 3:np
alfa{j,k} = a{j,k} - (b{j,k} * gamma{j-1,k});
gamma{j,k} = inv(alfa{j,k}) * c{j,k};
end
for j = 2:np
rr{j,k} = [r1(j,k); r2(j,k); r3(j,k); r4(j,k); r5(j,k); r6(j,k);...
r7(j,k)];
end
ww{2,k} = inv(alfa{2,k}) * rr{2,k};
 
for j = 3:np
ww{j,k} = inv(alfa{j,k}) * (rr{j,k} - (b{j,k} * ww{j-1,k}));
end
*******************************************************************
Backward Sweeping
*******************************************************************
delf(1,k) = 0.0;
delu(1,k) = 0.0;
delh(1,k) = 0.0;
delt(1,k) = 0.0;
delu(np,k) = 0.0;
delh(np,k) = 0.0;
dels(np,k) = 0.0;
dell{np,k} = ww{np,k};
for j = np-1:-1:2
dell{j,k} = ww{j,k} -(gamma{j,k} * dell{j+1,k});
end
delv(1,k) = dell{2,k}(1,1);
delp(1,k) = dell{2,k}(2,1);
dels(1,k) = dell{2,k}(3,1);
delf(2,k) = dell{2,k}(4,1);
delv(2,k) = dell{2,k}(5,1);
delp(2,k) = dell{2,k}(6,1);
delt(2,k) = dell{2,k}(7,1);
for j = np:-1:3
delu(j-1,k) = dell{j,k}(1,1);
delh(j-1,k) = dell{j,k}(2,1);
dels(j-1,k) = dell{j,k}(3,1);
delf(j,k) = dell{j,k}(4,1);
delv(j,k) = dell{j,k}(5,1);
delp(j,k) = dell{j,k}(6,1);
delt(j,k) = dell{j,k}(7,1);
end
 

*******************************************************************
Newton method
*******************************************************************
for j = 1:np
f(j,k+1) = f(j,k) + delf(j,k);
u(j,k+1) = u(j,k) + delu(j,k);
v(j,k+1) = v(j,k) + delv(j,k);
h(j,k+1) = h(j,k) + delh(j,k);
p(j,k+1) = p(j,k) + delp(j,k);
s(j,k+1) = s(j,k) + dels(j,k);
t(j,k+1) = t(j,k) + delt(j,k);
h(j,k+1) = -0.5 * v(j,k+1);
end
*******************************************************************
Convergence Check
*******************************************************************
stop = abs(delv(1,k));
kmax = k;
k = k + 1;
end
*******************************************************************
Skin Friction and Nusselt Number
*******************************************************************
cfrex = v(1,kmax)
nuxrex = 1/s(1,kmax)
nuxrex2 = s(1,kmax)
```

however, my case of study covers only the f, u and v, therefore, there are some changes on the initial condition. and many others part.

Comment: please show us the traceback including the repetition and the tutorial, you talk about.

Comment: can i show the matlab code that i used for reference? but its to large, how can i show it?

Comment: @faridCS227 If it's too large to put here, likely nobody will read it; But if you think it will be helpful, you can paste it at pastebin.com or somewhere similar, and link to that from here.

Comment: thanks, i hope someone can guide me with the transformation from matlab to python. i trying my best to prove that python can be used to solve mathematical problem, as good as matlab.

Comment: @faridCS227 Can you at least post the matlab code for the `alfa` and `gamma` functions?

Comment: @ewchan, i've posted the matlab i used as referential, there are changes here and there to fix in the scope covers for my study.

Comment: @faridCS227 I just saw this (my username is askewchan not ewchan, so I wasn't notified).  I still think that the problem (or at least one problem) is in the definitions of `alfa` and `gamma`.  In the MATLAB code, they are given initial conditions, which is not the case in your python code.

Comment: @askewchan are you referring to the alfa(2,k) and gamma(2,k) ? cuz if that is the problem then i should do that in the definition of alfa and gamma itself.

Comment: I don't see anything with `alfa(2,k)` or `gamma(2,k)`

Comment: @askewchan i've edited the codes, and add up the initial values as mentioned earlier but the program still produce the recursion errors. is that correct?

Comment: @askewchan i cant seem to find the solution, did u manage to get any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite recursion will occur in these two functions:

```
def alfa(j,k):
    return AJ(j,k) - (BJ(j,k)*gamma(j,k))
def gamma(j,k):
    return npy.matrix.I((alfa(g,k))*CJ(g,k))
```

Each of which calls the other one under any circumstances.  So, `alfa` calls `gamma` which calls `alfa` which calls `gamma` and so on forever.

We can see this if we add a print statement:

```
def alfa(j,k):
    print 'alfa({},{}) called'.format(j,k)
    return AJ(j,k) - (BJ(j,k)*gamma(j,k))
def gamma(j,k):
    print 'gamma({},{}) called'.format(j,k)
    return npy.matrix.I((alfa(g,k))*CJ(g,k))
```

Then we can see that this is what happens:

```
In [199]: alfa(3,1)
alfa(3,1) called
gamma(3,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
alfa(2,1) called
gamma(2,1) called
```

... and so on